# How do you ensure Dataflow Pipeline synchronicity in Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The Dataflow pipeline I've written ingests data that has been published synchronously. The order of this data does not matter, but it is published every second.

I need to output the result of the pipeline synchronously too, but at the moment I'm seeing inconsistent delays between the outputs of the pipeline.

I believe this can be solved with timers and triggers, but I can't workout how to use them correctly.

```py
| "Window"
    >> beam.WindowInto(
    window.FixedWindows(self.window_length),
    trigger=trigger.AfterProcessingTime(2),         
    accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING,
        # if message late by 700ms, still accept
        allowed_lateness=window.Duration(seconds=0.7)
)
```

The above method works but is still not synchronous. I had to add the processing time trigger to allow my other steps to run before the data is written to Firestore. It is a hacky workaround, and I need something more concrete.

The issue with my current implementation is that data is collected inside the window, with an allowed lateness of 700ms. Instead of the DoFn being in control of when data is emitted to Firestore, the window technically controls it. This means that it is not synchronous and the data does not arrive in Firestore every second.

Pipeline steps:

```
Step Group: Raw Data Processing
1. Read from PubSub
2. Deserialise message from Protobuf
3. Add message timestamp (window.TimestampedValue)

Raw Data Processing Step Group Branches to:
- Write data to BigQuery
- Step Group: Extra Processing

Step Group: Extra Processing
1. Add Key to data (for grouping)
2. Window data (as above)
3. Group data (GroupByKey())
4. Transform Data (custom ParDo())

Extra Processing Step Group Branches To:
- Write to Firestore (DoFn)
- Publish to PubSub topic
```

Is there any way of ensuring that my pipeline emits data to Firestore at exactly 1 second intervals?

Comment: I stumbled on this article while reviewing apache beam: 

[https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) at 11.3 there is a topic on timers, Might be helpful for your use case.

Comment: Please feel free to ask for any more details that will aid a solution.